# How can I add a symbol in front of specified symbols?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am having a string which includes also symbols like `'( ) |'` and maybe more in future.

I would like to `add` another symbol, in front of them.

String: `'Hi, my name | nick is Dave (for friends)'`
Expectation : `'Hi, my name /| nick is Dave /(for friends/)'`

So far I have tried `replace()` (replace only first one, failed), `replaceAll()` (didnt even work at all).

Right now I have this working code, but its too long, I would love to have one `regex`, where I specify all symbols, where I want to insert  the symbol '/' in front of.

Or any other solution to shorten the code, and make it more simple.

My working code, I would like to improve:

```
const string= 'Hi, my name | nick is Dave (for friends)'
   const firstString = string.split('|').join("/|")
   const secondString = firstString.split('(').join("/(")
   const thirdString = secondString.split(')').join("/)")
```

Result is `thirdString = 'Hi, my name /| nick is Dave /(for friends/)'`

Comment: You can use: `firstString.replace(/[|()]/g, '\\$&')`

Comment: @anubhava works! thanks! u can post this as answer so I can mark it as answered! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using `.replace` here instead of `.split`:

```
string.replace(/[|()]/g, '\\$&')
```

Here `[|()]` matches one of the given characters inside the character class and `'\\$&'` prepends `\` before the match.

**Code:**

```js
const string= 'Hi, my name | nick is Dave (for friends)';
var repl = string.replace(/[|()]/g, '\\$&');

console.log(repl);
//=> Hi, my name \| nick is Dave \(for friends\)
```